# bigobj option C++ compiler interfacing from Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, compiler-errors, compiler-optimization

I am using ACADO I would describe it as a framework but not sure it is. in short its a means for running optimization control where it searches for solution to differential equations driven by some controls that influence the results. now when I run my program I get the following error from the compiler

```
fatal error C1128: number of sections exceeded object file
format limit: compile with /bigobj
```

Now I can try to add this bigobj to the additional option using Visual studio but the cpp file is created from running the matlab code, the interface creates this cpp file and since the default obj size  65,279 (almost 2^16) addressable sections i get the error shown above. how can I set the default of the bigobj in my compiler

system windows10 home x64
matlab 2021b
microsoft visutal studio 2019
ACADO a link to their github https://acado.github.io/index.html

Comment: Does this help? https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/259136-specify-compiler-options-for-mex-command

Comment: I followed the method on the link, however no it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: an update to what I have  done so far. I tried calling the code as an m file form simulink where changed the configuration parameters of the build settings to specify then i added "/bigobj" in the C and C++ compiler space (not sure if this is the right way) but it is based on the matlab question I found on the mathworks forume : https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/374138-rapid-accelerator-mode-fatal-error-c1128?s_tid=mwa_osa_a
However the error still remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

If someone is still having this problem, here is what worked for me. I modified the `mexcall` field in the global variable `ACADO_` as follows:

```
global ACADO_;
ACADO_.mexcall = insertAfter(ACADO_.mexcall, "mex ", "COMPFLAGS='$COMPFLAGS -bigobj' ");
mpc.exportCode('export');
```

I'm using a Microsoft Visual Studio compiler. For MinGW, macOS, and Linux compilers it needs to be (cf. https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html):

```
ACADO_.mexcall = insertAfter(ACADO_.mexcall, "mex ", "CXXFLAGS='$CXXFLAGS -bigobj' ");
```

Comment: “For MinGW, macOS, and Linux compilers” — You mean for any compiler that is not MSVC… If MATLAB were still supported on Solaris, HPUX and SGI systems, the compiler variable would also be `CXXFLAGS`. I never understood why MSVC has to do things differently, but it surely is annoying!